# Detect Edge light/dark theme change

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Is there a way for a web page to detect when the theme in Microsoft Edge changes (Light/Dark)?

For example, if the application is running in high contrast I can use the -ms-hight-contrast to apply different CSS. For Edge Light/Dark theme, is there a similar media feature?

Answer (score 2):

To get the applied theme, Generally we can use Theme.getCurrent() method.

```
var getting = browser.theme.getCurrent(windowId) // integer
```

But at present, It is not supported by MS Edge.

Reference:

[theme.getCurrent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme/getCurrent)

As an alternative way. With Javascript code you can try to access the registry key value  to know which theme is applied currently.

You need to access value of key below.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main
```

Theme DWORD

0 = light theme

1 = dark theme

To get the JavaScript example to access Registry key, You can refer link below.

Reference:

[JScript/Javascript function to get a list of registry Values under Key](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/JScriptJavascript-function-d5ab014b)

Note:- Many times this folder is not available in registry. User need to create it first. In that situation, This method will not work.

Regards

Deepak